# How to wait for the animation to complete android

Tags: android

I want to setImageResource after the animation is finished.How should I go about?

```
image.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000f);
// now I want to wait for the animation to complete
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an api `setListener` which can be chained with `animate`. An example:

```
.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        // I can sneeze after tickling is completed
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an AnimatorListener like so:

```
image.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000f).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
    }
})
```

This way, by overriding the `onAnimationEnd()` method, you'll be able to run your `setImageResource()` code exactly when the animation ends.